# Unable to access own custom global function of shared library in linux from other module in C

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have downloaded `libgcrypt` library source code and 
added my own customize function inside one particular file.

Although compilation/build process of customized shared library is successful, and **both nm and objdump show
 the customized function is global**, **it nonetheless shows an error (undefined reference) at linking time.**

Here is what I have done:

inside /src/visibility.c file, I have added my custom function,

```
void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyFunction(void)
{
    printf("This is added just for testing purpose");   
}
```

## build process

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-ld-version-script

sudo make install
```

`nm` and `objdump` command find this custom function as global inside shared library.

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep MyFunction
000000000000fbf0 T MyFunction


objdump -t /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep MyFunction
000000000000fbf0 g     F .text  0000000000000013              MyFunction
```

Here is my sample code to access my custom function.

```
//gcrypt_example_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    MyFunction();
    return 0;
}


export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
gcc gcrypt_example_test.c -o test -lgcrypt
```

> /tmp/ccA0qgAB.o: In function `main':
>   gcrypt_example_test.c:(.text+0x3a2): undefined reference to `MyFunction'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Edit 1:**

I tried all possible way to include function prototype declaration inside header file (`/src/gcrypt.h`) as follows:

```
   void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyFunction(void);
```

... or:

```
    extern void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyFunction(void);
```

... or:

```
    extern void   MyFunction(void);
```

... or:

```
    void   MyFunction(void);
```

I am still getting the same error (`undefined reference`) although no build error results in all above cases.

**Why is this happening, and what mistake am I making?**

Although other global functions which are part of standard shared library and defined inside `visibility.c` (`nm` also shows `T` for those functions)  are accessible, why is my customized global function (`MyFunction`) of the shared library still inaccessible?  Thanks!

Any link or explanation to resolve this error will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Did you try to use a native gcrypt function? For checking purpose, to check if the problem is global or restricted to your own function.

Comment: @PicaudVincent, I used native gcrypt function (present in the visibility.c ) and it is working fine. When I tried to access my own customized function it failed.

Comment: Can you verify that the new gcrypt is installed (check the modified time) and if so where.

Comment: Ahh, see it below the code.  Try adding `-v` to the gcc command to see if that provides the extra detail needed.  Also, using `strace -f` on the `gcc` command will show exactly what files are being used, including all the libraries loaded by the linker.

Answer (score 4):

From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Some** linkers allow you to specify the path to the library by setting `LD_RUN_PATH` in your environment when linking.

But, [from the GNU `ld` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

```
   -rpath=dir
       Add a directory to the runtime library search path.  This is used
       when linking an ELF executable with shared objects.  All -rpath
       arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker,
       which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.  The -rpath
       option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed
       by shared objects explicitly included in the link; see the
       description of the -rpath-link option.  If -rpath is not used
       when linking an ELF executable, the contents of the environment
       variable "LD_RUN_PATH" will be used if it is defined.
```

Note that there is no mention at all of the **link time** library search path.

You need to compile/link with `/usr/local/lib` in the **link time** library search path:

```
gcc gcrypt_example_test.c -o test -L/usr/local/lib -lgcrypt
```

Comment: I already run command, export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib . So I think -L/usr/local/lib is not required.

Comment: @bholanath `-L` _is_ required.

Comment: This answer is correct. LD_RUN_PATH is not same as -L.  If -L is not used, then your linker probably uses wrong libgcrypt from /usr/lib/.

Comment: Try `ldd` on the executable to see where it's getting the library at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

most likely cause of the problem:

The header file for the library has not been updated to include the prototype for the new function

Comment: I also suspect that.

Comment: I have added the function prototype inside gcrypt.h header file and also included that header file in my sample c program.

Comment: nope, that is a whole different error (implicit declaration...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the reason behind why it is working now, but not before. Anyway, I found the way to make the code working after adding customized function inside standard library. This post may help others in future.

I first locate libgcrypt.so and then remove all versions of libgcrypt.so

```
locate libgcrypt.so


sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so 
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.20.2.2
```

then I delete the libgcrypt folder (which I had extracted  for building library) to start fresh.

Again, I follow these steps

Step 0 : extract libgcrypt source code

Step 1 : add my custom function, inside /src/visibility.c file

```
void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyFunction(void)
{
    printf("This is added just for testing purpose");   
}
```

Step 2 : build library

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-ld-version-script
sudo make install
```

Step 3: Open another terminal to compile

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
gcc gcrypt_example_test.c -o test -lgcrypt
```

Step 4 : run

```
./test
This is added just for testing purpose
```

This is working fine now as expected.

What I noticed that **__attribute__((visibility("default")))** in function definition and **--disable-ld-version-script** during build process is very important to make the customized function global, elimination of any makes the customized function local inside shared library(.so) file.

Comment: It's working because you installed the custom librcypto and it's libraries into your host system. Instead you can make use of  `-L/path` to compile.

Comment: @ThiruShetty, what do you mean by it worked as it is installed in host system ? After all, it has to installed in some machine . Do you want to say installation can be done in other's system ( client or server )?

Comment: Yes if the objective is to cross compile or need to build with particular version or multiple version. If your aim is for only your host system, then you can customize, compile and install.

Answer (score 0):

Below changes are working at my end

**visibility.h**

```
#include <cstdio>

void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyFunction(void);
```

**visibility.cpp**

```
#include "visibility.h"


void MyFunction(void)
{
    printf("This is added just for testing purpose");
}
```

**library build command**

```
gcc -shared -o libtest.so -Wall -Werror -fpic -I. visibility.cpp
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "visibility.h"

extern void MyFunction();

int main()
{
  MyFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

**exe build command**

```
gcc test.cpp -o test -I. -L. -ltest -lstdc++
```

My gcc version is 4.4.7

And of-course I did not try and install the lib under /usr/local/lib but kept it local for quick testing.

Comment: *Below changes are working at my end* Really?  Given *And of-course I did not try and install the lib under /usr/local/lib but kept it local for quick testing.*, this is a useless answer.

Comment: @anupkholgade, I have already done whatever you are suggested.  I am interested to make changes with standard library, by adding my own custom function inside standard library , building standard library with my added custom function.